# How can you sort by descending date/time on the Kibana "Discover" tab.

Tags: elasticsearch

Kibana is a tool that exposes data stored in Elastic Search.  Is there way to sort the data on the discover tab by descending date/time, kind of like an EventLog.  I have various messages with different index/types being emitted from my programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you have a datetime in a field of type "text", you cannot sort on "text" fields.  When I figure out how to set the data type, I'll update it in post I made on Stackoverflow, because the answer for that involves code, whereas this question was hoping to use the native features of Kibana to simply sort on an existing field.

if the field is a string or a datetime, looks like you can click an icon to make it a column, then the column headings will have an up/down arrow allowing you to sort.  Text fields just lack this feature.  (See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-sort-by-date-time-on-kibana-discover/126804/8).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634743/how-can-you-sort-by-descending-date-time-on-the-kibana-discover-tab